# Make vim's {} motions skip over folds

Tags: vim

I love vim's `{` and `}` motions, which jump to the next/previous empty line.

I've recently been using folding more, and while that's a great feature, it doesn't do what I would expect with respect to the `{` and `}` motions. If there is an empty line in the fold, then `{` and `}` will land there, thus opening the fold.

Is there a way to remap `{` and `}` to skip folds altogether? That is, even if there were empty lines inside a fold, `{` and `}` would not stop there but would seek the next unfolded empty line? This would fit better with what I would expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### First question:

You must remove `block` from the default value of `'foldopen'`:

```
set foldopen-=block
```

See `:help 'foldopen'`.

#### Second question:

You can try these mappings

```
nnoremap <expr> } foldclosed(search('^$', 'Wn')) == -1 ? "}" : "}j}"
nnoremap <expr> { foldclosed(search('^$', 'Wnb')) == -1 ? "{" : "{k{"
```

Comment: This is much better, thanks! But it's not quite what I asked. I want to skip folds altogether, such that even if there is an empty line, the cursor doesn't stop there upon a `{` or `}`.

Comment: My answer addressed your first question. If you have multiple questions ask them separately. If they are all linked by a common subject, ask about that subject instead.

Comment: @JeffTerrellPh.D. please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the followup. The `nnoremap` commands make fewer folded empty lines catch the cursor, but if there are two empty lines in a single fold, the second will still catch the cursor. I want to skip _all_ folded empty lines, not just some. Also, I only ever intended to ask one question. The second question above was intended to clarify the intent of the first question, not pose a new question. Thanks!

Comment: You currently have two questions on superuser which should have been asked together.

Comment: I just tested with three blank lines in a fold and the commands above correctly skip the fold.

Comment: Interesting. It wasn't working for my markdown folds, but maybe that was because something in the [unofficial markdown folding plugin](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding) isn't working right. I can't get it to break on simple examples, so I'll assume your solution works. Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the extra trouble!

Answer (score 1):

This method takes into account multiple consecutive folds.

```
function! s:SkipFold(direction) abort
  let l:currentLine = line('.')
  while foldclosed(l:currentLine) != -1
    let l:currentLine = search('^$', (a:direction ? 'Wn' : 'Wnb'))
    if l:currentLine == 0
      if a:direction
        call cursor(line('$'), strlen(getline(line('$'))))
      else
        call cursor(1, 1)
      endif
      break
    endif
    call cursor(l:currentLine, 0)
  endwhile
endfunction

nnoremap <silent>} }:call <SID>SkipFold(1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent>{ {:call <SID>SkipFold(0)<cr>
```